# Javascript await fetch GET request with number of params

Tags: javascript, reactjs

React JSX project.
I'm trying to execute await fetch GET request with number of params, fails with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error.
While executing the same request with Postman, it works fine.

Some syntax issue I have. What am I doing wrong?

First of all, I'm initializing the uri to some proper value.

Secondly, I'm preparing the GET options:

```
var options = (payload) => {
  return {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    param: JSON.stringify(payload) //payload is {domainName: "idoidoido.info"}
  };
};
```

Then, await fetch:

```
  const response = await fetch(uri, options(param));
```

And, it fails with `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier` error...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Succeded to solve this. Looks like query params can't be part of fetch GET request.

Solved this by preparing the request URL beforehand with [URI.js](https://medialize.github.io/URI.js/).

So, the option:

```
const options = () => {
  return {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Accept: 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    credentials: 'same-origin'
  };
};
```

Then, await fetch:

```
  const URI = require('urijs');

  const request = new URI(uri).addSearch(params).toString();
  const response = await fetch(uri, options());
```

The `addSearch(params)` appending the params nicely to the url:

```
URI("?hello=world")
    .addSearch("hello", "mars")
        // -> ?hello=world&hello=mars
    .addSearch({ foo: ["bar", "baz"] })
        // -> ?hello=world&hello=mars&foo=bar&foo=baz
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming the second parameter of `fetch` takes an object, but your `options` is a function, which must be called with the payload, so I should think your code should be

```
const response = await fetch(uri, options(somePayload));
```

Comment: Thanks, the payload was there. Just forgot to write it here :)

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, I hope you're using a transpiler like BabelJS, otherwise this would would fail on like 99% of all targets at present.

Your code looks fine. Since `fetch` returns a Promise, `await` can deal with it. But you have to make sure that your `await` statement always is located within an `async function` declaration. Otherwise an error is thrown at you.

So make sure your calling line has a structure like

```
async function getData( uri, options ) {
    const response = await fetch(uri, options);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I did later, didn't helped. Looks like 'param' can't be passed as part of options.